# .Net TreeView EndUpdate is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, treeview

We have a legacy application written in C++/CLI (WinForm) and it displays a complex treeview with nearly 10K elements.
Adding/Removing/Renaming the tree nodes are wrapped in BeginUpdate/EndUpdate methods. The problem is with EndUpdate() method, that it takes nearly 180 seconds to complete. It takes same time even when only 100 nodes are visible and others are collapsed.Since it take same time for EndUpdate() method, i guess TreeView is painting the nodes even they are not visible. Is there any way to prevent the painting of treenode that is not visible?
Please suggest on ways improve this painting speed?
Note: DoubleBuffered property of treeview is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    Visible = false;
    ...
    Visible = true;
```

In my case(2000 nodes), it takes only 1~2 seconds to load the tree, which is much more quicker than any other ways.